# Auto-change font-family at certain interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fonts

I hope you are able to point me in the right direction with this.

I want to create a website where the font-family changes at a certain interval. And then just loops. For example:

1. Text starts in Arial
2. Changes to Times New Roman
3. Changes to Verdana
4. Changes back into Arial again - and so forth

How can this be done? Every time I search for this, I only get solutions for how to make the font-size or font-color auto change at a certain interval, but never the font-family. If you could tell me which method to use here, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Javascript can set CSS properties. So all you have to do is use CSS to set your first font on the body. Then you create a couple of functions. Each function changes the CSS property of body to a different font. Put a timeout in the function that calls the next function and make the last one call the first function again to create an infinite loop. - Currently working on an example code for you.

Comment: BTW: that would suck for usability

Comment: God that's something I wish i'll never see.

Comment: After seeing the answers already given, mine would be extremely bad. So I leave it up to those.

Answer (score 2):

A Simple way do this:

```js
var fonts = ['times', 'verdana', 'arial'];
var currentFont = 0

function changeFont() {
  document.body.style.fontFamily = fonts[currentFont++ % fonts.length]
}

setInterval(changeFont, 1000);
```

```html
My font will change
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a css class attribute to all parts of  your page you want to be affected; lets say : `class="my_font_family_class"`

Then, here is the code to process :

```
window.myInterval= 3600 * 1000;// every hour
window.fontFamilies =["Arial","Times New Roman", "Verdana" ];
window.fontFamilyCounter=0;
setInterval(function(){
   $('.my_font_family_class').css("font-family", window.fontFamilies[window.fontFamilyCounter % window.fontFamilies.length]);
   window.fontFamilyCounter ++;
}, window.myInterval);
```